# Calculating Conditional Probability in Real Data

Tags: dataset, conditional-probability, application

I have my data in the form as:

```
+----------+------------+-------+
| AuthorID | CoAuthorID | Year  |
+----------+------------+-------+
|  677     | 901706     |  2005 |
|  677     | 901706     |  2005 |
|  677     | 901706     |  2005 |
|  677     | 838459     |  2007 |
|  677     | 901706     |  2007 |
|  677     | 1695352    |  2007 |
|  677     | 901706     |  2009 |
|  677     | 372089     |  2011 |
|  677     | 403400     |  2011 |  
|  ...     |            |       |
|  ...     |            |       |
+----------+------------+-------+
```

I want to calculate **yearly** conditional probability for `AuthorID` given `CoAuthorID`
whereas the formula for calculating conditional probability is:

```
P(AuthorID|CoAuthorID) = (P(CoAuthorID|AuthorID) * P(AuthorID)) / P(CoAuthorID)
```

For instance if `AuthorID` is `677` and `CoAuthorID` is `901706` and we have to calculate `Conditional Probability` between them, then values for:
`P(AuthorID)            = P(677)        = 1/390  = 0.00256`
`P(CoAuthorID)          = P(901706)     = 1/1    = 1.000`
`P(CoAuthor(D|AuthorID) = P(901706|677) = 5      = 5`

For sake of explaining my calculations:

1. For `P(AuthorID)`, I have divided it with total number of
   `AuthorID`s in data as `1/390`
2. For `P(CoAuthorID)`, I have divided
       it with total number of `CoAuthorID`s for the `AuthorID` i.e.
       `677` in year `2005` as `1/1` For    `P(CoAuthorID|AuthorID)`, I have counted
       total number of occurrences    where `AuthorID` and `CoAuthorID`
       co-exists, as there were `5` so I put this in there.

Now I want to ask these:

1. Should I take `AuthorID` only for year 2005 i.e. `390` or whole `AuthorID` count i.e. `499`?
2. I have counted `CoAuthorID` only for `AuthorID` i.e. `677` for
   calculating `P(CoAutohrID)` as `1/13`. Is it right or should I have
   to consider total number of `CoAuthorID` i.e. `19411`
3. I have put `5` for `P(CoAuthorID|AuthorID)`, considering only number
   of co-existence of `AuthorID` and `CoAuthorID` in whole data. Is it
   right or have I to divide it by some other value to calculate it?

Actually I know well about conditional probability as I have googled it and found examples relating only to `Card`, `Deck`, `Dice` or `Coin` but here is some sort of application that's why facing some application problems in understanding the concept.

I have tried this:

```
P(677)          =   1/390   0.0026  (AuthorID/Total AuthorID in 2005)
P(901706)       =   1/1     1.00    (CoAuthorID/Total CoAuthorID for AuthorID in 2005)
P(901706|677)   =   5       5.0     (Total CoAuthorID|AuthorID pairs in data)
P(901706|677)   =   3       3.0     (Total CoAuthorID|AuthorID pairs in data in 2005)
P(901706|677)   =   3/5     0.60    (CoAuthorID|AuthorID pairs in data in 2005/Total CoAuthorID|AuthorID pairs)
```

Which calculation is right for corresponding values required to put in to the formula of conditional probability ?

Please help in this regard.
Thanks!

Comment: @RichardHardy--Can you answer it?